# Verify that One Radio Button in Every Div has been Selected In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, emotion

I have a series of multiple choice questions. Each answer option is implemented as a radio button. I would like, when the user has selected an answer/radio button for every question in the quiz to display a pie chart.

This is what I have so far (please mind the uppercases, I'm using Emotion)

```
class Budget extends React.Component {
    state = {
      studentLoanPayment: 0,
      emergencyfund: 0,
      401k: 0
    };

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        console.log(name, value, event.target)

        this.setState({
          [name]: value,
          selected: event.target.id
        });
    };

    render() {
      const {
          studentLoanPayment,
          emergencyfund,
          401k
      } = this.state;


        return (
          <div>
              <UL>
                  <Li>
                      <h4>
                          How much money should Leif put towards student loans
                          each month?
                      </h4>
                  </Li>
                  <li>
                              <Label>
                                  <input
                                      id="q00"
                                      type="radio"
                                      name="studentLoanPayment"
                                      value="400"
                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                  />
                                  400
                                 {this.state.selected === "q00" && <DynamicText>hidden op1 text</DynamicText>}
                              </Label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                              <Label>
                                  <input
                                      id="q01"
                                      type="radio"
                                      name="studentLoanPayment"
                                      value="500"
                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                  />
                                  500
                                  {this.state.selected === "q01" && <DynamicText>hidden op1 text</DynamicText>}
                              </Label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Label>
                      <input
                        id="q02"
                        type="radio"
                        name="studentLoanPayment"
                        value="200"
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                      </input>
                      200
                      {this.state.selected === "q02" && <DynamicText>hidden op1 text</DynamicText>}
                    </Label>
                 </li>
              </UL>
              <UL>
                  <li>
                      <h4>
                          How much money should Leif put towards an emergency fund?
                      </h4>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                              <Label>
                                  <input
                                      id = "q10"
                                      type="radio"
                                      name="emergencyfund"
                                      value="1,000"
                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                  />
                                  1,000
                                  {this.state.selected === "q10" && <DynamicText>hidden op1 text</DynamicText>}
                              </Label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                              <label>
                                  <input
                                      id = "q11"
                                      type="radio"
                                      name="emergencyfund"
                                      value="200"
                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                  />
                                  200
                                  {this.state.selected === "q11" && <DynamicText>hidden op1 text</DynamicText>}
                              </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                  <Label>
                      <input
                        id = "q12"
                        type="radio"
                        name="emergencyfund"
                        value="0"
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                      0
                      {this.state.selected === "q12" && <DynamicText>hidden op1 text</DynamicText>}
                    </Label>
                 </li>
              </UL>

              <UL>
                  <li>
                      <h2>
                          How much money should Leif put towards their 401(k)?
                      </h2>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                              <label>
                                  <input
                                      type="radio"
                                      name="401k"
                                      value="400"
                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                  >
                                  </input>
                              </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                              <label>
                                  <input
                                      type="radio"
                                      name="401k"
                                      value="500"
                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                  >
                                  </input>
                              </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="401k"
                      value="200"
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                    </input>
                 </li>
              </UL>

              <VictoryPie
                  colorScale="green"
                  data={[
                    {x: "Student Loans", y: this.state.studentLoanPayment},
                    {x: "Emergency Fund", y: this.state.emergencyfund}
                  ]}
                  labels={d => `${d.x}: ${d.y}%`}
                  style={{ parent: { maxWidth: '50%' } }}
              />
          </div>


        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way in react to go through all the radio buttons in a certain `div` (or in this case a `ul`) ? That way I could loop through them and make sure one is selected. And then perhaps loop through all the `ul`s in the document (in other words - loop through all the questions in the quiz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that. if you were to structure your data, you would make it far easier.

E.g. you could do something like this:

```
const data = {
  questions: [
    {
      id: 'q00',
      accessor: 'studentLoanPayment',
      value: 400,
    },
    {
      id: 'q01',
      accessor: 'studentLoanPayment',
      value: 500,
    },
    {
      id: 'q10',
      accessor: 'emergencyFund',
      value: 1000,
    },
    {
      id: 'q11',
      accessor: 'emergencyFund',
      value: 200,
    },
    {
      id: 'q20',
      accessor: '401k',
      value: 500,
    },
  ],
  selectedQuestions: {},
};
```

Of course the data should be in your state(e.g. you get it from some api and load it on componentDidMount). Then map through them and display them as desired.

*Note* that you should use `selectedQuestions` to fill in the question selected by the user based on their `accessor`. For example,

```
- How much money should Leif put towards student loans
                          each month?
User selects q01 => your: 
data = {
   questions: [...],
   selectedQuestions: { q01: true }
}
```

And so forths. Hope that helps!

Comment: would I still be using radio buttons?

Comment: what is an `accessor`?

Comment: could you perhaps show how to map through them and display them?

Comment: is `User selects q01 => your` react syntax?

Comment: The accessor could be like has that has the answerOption. So that you know which answer selected.

Comment: No that's not a syntax of React. But just to demonstrate what I meant! I'll make a sandbox for you

Comment: Check out this https://codesandbox.io/embed/sleepy-keldysh-zc1fl?fontsize=14. I'll edit my answer accordingly!

Comment: But you can now build up from there!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197699/discussion-between-maddie-and-hasan-sh).